# Conditional querying to return timestamp if NOT todays date , else return time

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I have an SQL query where I want to retrieve timestamp records from a table.

The query however must return only the time without time zone if todays date = timestamp in that record.

If the record's timestamp::date is NOT equals to todays date then return the timestamp. Examples:

```
2013-08-07 18:00:18.692+01
2013-08-09 20:13:09.927+01
```

Expected result:

```
18:00:18.692 
2013-08-09 20:13:09.927+01
```

From those two timestamps I would like to be able to retrieve just the time from the 1st as it is todays date but retrieve both the date and time from the second as it is NOT todays date

Comment: Can you show some example data?

Comment: "2013-08-07 18:00:18.692+01" , "2013-08-09 20:13:09.927+01"....From those two timestamps I would like to be able to retrieve just the time from the 1st as it is todays date but retrieve both the date and time from the second as it is NOT todays date

Comment: Please add that and other values to your question along with the expected result of the query. So we can see what data matches and which should not.

Comment: The expected result from the 1st timestamp would be 18:00:18.692 and the expected result from the 2nd timestamp would be 2013-08-09 20:13:09.927+01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially a formatting issue, so it might be better to handle it in application code. But you *can* do it in SQL.

```
create table t (
  ts timestamp not null
  );

insert into t values 
('2013-01-01 08:00');
insert into t values 
(current_timestamp);
```

The time and timestamp data types aren't compatible in the way you want to return them, so casting to text makes sense.

```
select case when ts::date = current_date then ts::time::text
            else ts::text
       end
from t;

TS
--
2013-01-01 08:00:00
16:34:52.339
```

Answer (score 0):

Which database?

The dates are always stored with the date portion so this seems like a formatting question.  I have a solution below but the actual format may be a little off.  The question seemed to be about the logic and you can easily research formatting strings to get what you want.

Here is an Oracle solution:
(Notice I create an inline view with a UNION from DUAL to simulate your data.  Just add your table there.)

```
select dt, when,
case
  when trunc(sysdate) = trunc(dt) then to_char(dt, 'hh24:mi:ss')
  else to_char(dt, 'yyyy-dd-mm hh24:mi:ss')
end  yourResult
from
(
  select sysdate dt, 'today' when
  from dual
  union
  select sysdate-1 dt, 'yesterday' when
  from dual
);
```

Here is a SQL Server solution:
(Again, there is an inline view to simulate your data)

```
select dt, whn,
case
  when cast(getDate() As Date) = cast(dt As Date) then convert(varchar(20), dt, 108)
  else convert(varchar(20), dt, 120 )
end  your_Result
from
(
    select getDate() dt, 'today' whn
    union
    select getDate()-1 dt, 'yesterday' whn
)  x;
```

Comment: I have a table with a column of timestamps in it , and i want to retrieve all the records in that column. 

The records returned that are todays date must only be returned in time form (no need for todays date) and records that are not equal to todays date must show date and time.

Comment: I think this is what my answer does.  Which database are you using?  Let me know if there are problems with my solution and I will fix it.  If it works, please mark it as the answer.